# inserting random numbers into array Java

Tags: java, arrays, hash, hashtable

I have to hash 900 random integers into an empty table that has a set size of 1009 using open addressing. To determine where the number should go in the table I take the random number mod 1009 and then place the number there if it is open. If not I should check the next key after that and keep checking one by one until I find an open one to place the random number. The code I have so far is this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class openAdd{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    //set table length
    int[] table = new int[1009];

    //insert 900 random integers into the table using open addressing
    //random number % table size = the key the number should be placed
    //if the key is already taken go to the next key until you find an open one
    Random randomGenerator = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < 900; i++) {
        int num = randomGenerator.nextInt(99999);
        int key = num % 1009;
        if (table[key] == 0) {
            table[key] = num;
        }
    }
}
```

}

I think what I have so far is good I am just confused on how to go about setting the key to key + 1 if there is already something in the original key. Thank you for your help, and just let me know if I need to add anything.

Comment: Are you asking how to increment a variable?

Comment: kind of, Im thinking I should include an else statement after the if and then have a for loop inside that and then once I find a key that == 0 I should place the number there.

Comment: Sounds about right.

Comment: I am just not sure what to put into the for loop, and then once I reach the end of the array and its still all full how do I go back to the beginning of it to continue the check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have the right idea, just not the right implementation. If `table[key]` is nonzero, then you need to increment `key` until you find an index in `table` where `table[key]` is zero. You can utilize Java's remainder operator (like you already are) to prevent `key` from increasing over the bound of the array:

```
int key = num % 1009;

if (table[key] == 0) {
    table[key] = num;
} else {
    while (table[key = (key + 1) % table.length] != 0);
    table[key] = num;
}
```

Because `table.length` is greater than the amount of elements you're setting, there's no need to check if the array is *full*. Also, keep in mind that `num` can be `0`.

Comment: thank you, this answers my original question perfectly! If the key + 1 does go all the way to the end of the table, because it could start almost at the end, does the key +1 go back to 0 after it reaches the end?

Comment: If you use `(key + 1) % table.length`, then it will go back to `0` after reaching the end.

Comment: Although it's true that you don't need to check if the array is full *in this case*, the reality is that somebody is likely to use this code in some other situation. And it will go into an infinite loop when the table is full. You should add the full check to "future proof" your code.